# Composer - uncommited changes (symfony 2.1)

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I am using symfony 2.1 with composer and I'm trying to run **composer update**

However, I keep getting **"has uncommitted changes"**, I don't remember changing any of the files in the vendors dir and it comes up with almost every package!

I tried **composer install** to revert any changes, but it doesn’t seem to have an effect. If I delete the lock file and try an **install**, I get error messages like "symfony 2.1 requires symfony 2.1 -> symfony 2.1 satisfiable". It just doesn’t make sense.

If I delete the contents in vendors I get the same error messages and nothing installs.

Nothing I do seems to work. Is there a way to update with **"force"** regardless of **"uncommitted changes"**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `composer status -v`. Here's how you can detect a file change in `vendor/` using this command, and how to fix it.

First, we verify that no package is modified:

```
➜  SymfonyApp git:(master) ✗ composer status
No local changes
```

Then, we change a vendor file

```
➜  SymfonyApp git:(master) ✗ echo "modification" >> vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php
```

We then ask composer to tell us about modified vendor files (note the -v option, to see the modified files)

```
➜  SymfonyApp git:(master) ✗ composer status -v
You have changes in the following dependencies:
/Users/adrienbrault/Developer/SymfonyApp/vendor/symfony/symfony:
    M src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php
```

We then reset the vendor git repository to set the files back to their original state.

```
➜  SymfonyApp git:(master) ✗ cd /Users/adrienbrault/Developer/SymfonyApp/vendor/symfony/symfony
➜  symfony  git checkout .
➜  symfony  cd -
~/Developer/SymfonyApp
```

Finally, we check that the files are not seen as modified anymore by composer.

```
➜  SymfonyApp git:(master) ✗ composer status -v
No local changes
```

Update: composer should now help you to handle this

Comment: thank you very much :) worked. However before I post another SO post. have you come across this before:  sensio/framework-extra-bundle dev-master requires symfony/framework-bundle 2.2.* -> no matching package found. thanks again

Comment: update: don't use dev-master in composer. Get the new composer.json from the symfony release 2.1.1

Comment: What if the vendor folder is ignored from git?

Answer (score 11):

You can also set the `discard-changes` to `true` in the config parameter of your composer.json file, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#discard-changes.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "description": "Demonstrating concepts",
...
  "config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800,
    "discard-changes" : true
  },
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because this affected various projects sharing dependencies on one server, since for example a vender author would ask me to test quick changes before filing bugs and committing to their repo,  I ran this to globally set **discard-changes** to **true**:

```
php composer.phar config -g  discard-changes 1
```